# Sometimes HTML References Do Not Work

Tags: vba, excel

Ok, here goes. I'm experiencing an intermittent problem using 2010 Excel VBA. I have written some complex-ish code to interact with several websites to gather information. This works flawlessly, except on occasion. The problem is not in the code, rather the references. Occasionally, I get the problem cited:

"Compile error:

Object library feature not supported"

The snag occurs on setting the HTML Document from the web page. In order to fix this problem, all I have to do is deselect the "Microsoft Internet Controls" and "Microsoft HTML Object Library" references, save the file, then re-select those references, and it works well for weeks at a time. This occurs seemingly randomly on multiple computers from multiple users.

As the use for the Macro enabled excel file continues to expand across my company, this will become a major headache to quickly fix this problem for other users, knowing it will happen again. How do I prevent this reference "forgetfulness" permanently?

Thank you for any help in advance.

Note: I did not post any code because it works as designed whenever this reference issue is noted. The piece of code that is affected is

"Set doc = ie.document"

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that one or more of the users has a differnt version of IE. When they open the file it (re)sets the ref to their .dll versions and that ref sticks from then on. I'm guessing their version is higher based on issues i've had in the past. You can probably verify by checking properties for ieframe.dll and mshtml.tbl on all machines.

I've run into similar issues reffing Excel/Word/ETC in Access when users have different versions of office. I resolved by creating the object from it's most generic class rather than using references. The Pros are no refs required and versions don't usually matter. Cons are you don't get object browser info, versions sometimes matter, can't use WithEvents and are sort of coding blindly so you have to know what you're doing.

Here's a basic example of how to utlize IE without references. Just paste it into a new Excel file's ThisWorkbook Module to test it.

```
Function IEWithNoRefs() As Long
  Dim ie As Object
  Dim doc As Object
  Dim elm As Object

  Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application", vbNullString) 'create a generic IE Application Object
  'NOTE: you probably don't need 'Microsoft HTML Object Library' at all      
  ie.Visible = True 'use it just as you would when referenced...the only dif is you wont get anything when typing a period
  ie.navigate "https://google.com"

  While ie.ReadyState <> 4 'sort of simulating WithEvents OnDocumentComplete; probably a better way, but regardless....you can't work with Document until it's loaded!
    DoEvents
  Wend

  Set doc = ie.Document 'generic ref to IE's document object
  Set elm = doc.getelementsbytagname("input")(0) 'generic ref to the first <input in the docs elements list

  MsgBox elm.Name 'proove that we have valid ref

ErrHandler:
  Set elm = Nothing
  Set doc = Nothing
  Set ie = Nothing
  If err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox err.Description, vbExclamation, "Error " & err.Number
  End If

End Function
```

This should work on any computer with IE installed, regardless of version.

If you're just doing basic DOM interaction, then subtle version differences should not be an issue. (but of course they might!)

Chances are that in your current code, you can simply remove the references, replace:

```
Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
Set ie = New InternetExplorer
```

with

```
Dim ie As Object
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application", vbNullString)
```

, and change any existing variable/parameter types to Object.

From:

```
Dim doc As IHTMLDocument 'requires reference
Function SomeFunction(doc As IHTMLAnchorElement)
```

To:

```
Dim doc As Object 'does not require reference
Function SomeFunction(doc As Object)
```

The rest of your code could very well work fine after doing this :)